# Php session not opening correctly on all pages

Tags: php, session

So I created this little login system for my php site, I have a login form where I first create the session with a few session variables like UserId and such.
I also do session_destroy() before i create the session so that any existing session will be destroyed.

Then I have this php file that I include on the top of every page on my site which opens that session with `session_start()` and starts the mysql connection and such.

Problem is, on some pages the session does open correctly and on other pages seems to create a new session. In fact if I go to another page and return to the page where the correct session isn't opening it's the same incorrect session, so I actually have two sessions opened it seems...

When I echo the session ID on page where it works and the one where it doesnt, they have different session ID's so I'm confused.

Comment: I lost my crystal ball somewhere - you will have to post your code...

Comment: can you check your php session cookies for both, are they set to same domain/url on both instances?

Comment: sounds like it could be a cookie domain/path issue. If you are getting duplicate cookies, check their paths.

Comment: Make sure to always check for a session before starting one. if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();

Comment: Don’t save your UTF-8 files with BOM as it creates issues and maybe this problem is for that cause.

Comment: I can't really post code, everything is pretty much written here, unless you want me to paste a few hundered lines of irrelevant code here

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, one cookie is set to domain.com and the other to www.domain.com so that's probably the cause, not sure how I can fix that though. I'm using cloudflare so everything automatically gets forwarded to the www., or atleast i thought so

Comment: Alright, that was the issue, the www. was attached to one cookie but not the other, I'll add some code to make sure everything stays on the www. version, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IF you are getting duplicate cookies (as is in this case), check the domain and path of each cookie. Make sure the cookie path are domain are always set to the same domain and path is always the root of your website (assuming you want the cookies site-global).

Each cookie is visible to the set path and domain, all paths starting with the path set, and may be set to match all subdomains of the domain.

Based on the comments to the question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't use `session_destroy()` as it will delete the session on the next page request. Instead use:

```
unset( $_SESSION ); //this will delete the session immediately
```

To try and test the problem use the `session_id()` function:

```
<?php
    $a = session_id();
    if(empty($a)) session_start();
    echo "SID: ".SID."<br>session_id(): ".session_id()."<br>COOKIE: ".$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"];
?>
```

Comment: Well replacing it with unset seems to just destroy my login system entirely. And it's still working with two different sessions :/